# Counting data across two different dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, ipython

I have this casestudy to fix:

I have 2 different dataframes, I would like to fill "arrivals" column (hospital data) in DF1 counting all the pat arrived in DF2 according to the datetime in DF1 (in excel is a count if function). For example in DF1 I have datetime = 2013-01-01 and I go to count  all the patient arrived in DF2 (arrival column) = 2 and storing the result in "ARRIVALS" (DF1).

```
DF1

    patient datetime    arrivals    departures  occupancy   dayofweek
0   pat 2013-01-01  0   0   0   1
1   pat 2013-01-02  0   0   0   2
2   pat 2013-01-03  0   0   0   3
3   pat 2013-01-04  0   0   0   4
4   pat 2013-01-05  0   0   0   5

DF2


category    Arrival     departures  occupancy   dayofweek
0   pat 2013-01-01  2013-01-02  0   
1   pat 2013-01-01  2013-01-02  2
2   pat 2013-01-03  2013-01-15  3
3   pat 2013-01-04  2013-01-20  4
4   pat 2013-01-05  2013-01-20  5
```

Answer (score 0):

You could first do a groupby on DF2, counting one of the columns, and then  merge the resulting DataFrame with DF1, something like this:

```
df2_gr = df2.groupby('Arrival')['category'].count().reset_index()

df3 = df1.merge(df2_gr, left_on='datetime', right_on='Arrival', how='left').fillna(0)
```

Comment: I have tried as you said but I didn't got a good result (I posted the result below)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're looking for groupby. Something like this should work. You'll need to take care of the nans from the count.

```
import pandas as pd

d1 = pd.DataFrame([['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'], ['blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah']]).T
d2 = pd.DataFrame([['A', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'D'], ['blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah']]).T

unique_counts = d2.groupby(0).count()

pd.merge(d1, unique_counts, left_on=0, right_index=True, how='outer')
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to apply your answers but I do not get good results as you can see below: I just have the same value 1970 -01-01 instead of having a column with the same value stored in datetime column. Arrival column is empty instead of having the count of arrivals as needed (from df1)

```
df3 = pandas.merge(df1,df2_gr, left_on='datetime', right_on ='Datain',how='left').fillna(0)
df3

   category datetime    arrivals    departures  occupancy   dayofweek   Arrival category
0   pat 2013-01-01  0   0   0   1   1970-01-01  0
1   pat 2013-01-02  0   0   0   2   1970-01-01  0
2   pat 2013-01-03  0   0   0   3   1970-01-01  0
3   pat 2013-01-04  0   0   0   4   1970-01-01  0
4   pat 2013-01-05  0   0   0   5   1970-01-01  0
5   pat 2013-01-06  0   0   0   6   1970-01-01  0
6   pat 2013-01-07  0   0   0   0   1970-01-01  0
7   pat 2013-01-08  0   0   0   1   1970-01-01  0
8   pat 2013-01-09  0   0   0   2   1970-01-01  0
```